# The maketitle command fails when using the APA7 package

Tags: packages, apa7

I have been struggled to follow APA7 package instructions. I don't understand why \maketitle command just won't work. Even if I put title page before \begin{document}, the code still fails.

Here is the reference to APA7 package on CTAN: http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa7/apa7.pdf.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,doc,noextraspace]{apa7}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
% \usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\intextsep}{5pt}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\linespread{1.25}

% colors for hyperlinks
% colored borders (false) colored text (true)
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}

% package for bibliography
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
% package for header
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[]{Name1,Name2,Name3}
\ohead[]{\today}
\cfoot[]{\pagemark} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
    \title{
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        % \flushleft
            \includegraphics[width=0.26\textwidth]{pic_lib/icon.png}
    \end{figure}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \Huge Project II\\
    }
    
    % if you are the only author, you might use the following
    % \author{Name of student}  
    
    % Insert here your name and correct mail address
    \author{
        \href{mailto:a}{1} \\
    \href{mailto:a}{2}\\
    \href{mailto:a}{3}
    }
    
    
    % name of the course and module
    \date{
    \large Course: 0 \\ 
    \vspace{0.8cm}
    \large Lecturer: 0 \\
    \vspace{1cm}
    \today
    }

% \begin{document}
\maketitle 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CONTENT PAGE
\newpage
\tableofcontents
    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%          Problem Set 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage

\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Problem Set 2}
\section*{Problem Set 2}
\label{sec:ps2}

\section{Problem}
\label{sub:Problem}

.......
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- don't use `scrlayer-scrpage` with the apa7 class. The class already uses the `fancyhdr` package for the headers and footers, so you can simply use the macros from this package
- don't use a floating `figure` environment inside the title macro, that makes no sense
- load `hyperref` after the other packages
- are you really sure that your encoding is `utf8x`? That's highly usual in this  millennium...
- don't abuse `\\` for line breaks
- `apa7` has it's own mechanism to deal with multiple authors and add information like the curse or lecturer to the title page

--

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,stu,noextraspace]{apa7}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
% \usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\intextsep}{5pt}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\linespread{1.25}

% colors for hyperlinks
% colored borders (false) colored text (true)
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\lhead{Name1,Name2,Name3}%
\rhead{\today}%
\cfoot{\thepage}%



\begin{document}
    \title{Project II}
    
    % if you are the only author, you might use the following
    % \author{Name of student}  
    
    % Insert here your name and correct mail address
    \authorsnames{\href{mailto:a}{1},\href{mailto:a}{2},\href{mailto:a}{3}}
    \authorsaffiliations{}
%    
%    

%    % name of the course and module
    \duedate{\today}
        \course{Course: 0}
        \professor{Lecturer: 0}

% \begin{document}
{\flushleft  \includegraphics[width=0.26\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}

\maketitle 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CONTENT PAGE
\newpage
\tableofcontents
    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%          Problem Set 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage

\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Problem Set 2}
\section*{Problem Set 2}
\label{sec:ps2}

\section{Problem}
\label{sub:Problem}

.......
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am getting used to apa7 package. You really saved my day XD